# Unable to configure backend for Oracle cloud in terraform version 1.6.4 getting error authorisation header malformed

Tags: terraform, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am using credentials file for declaring backend in main.tf

access_key                  = "~/.aws/credentials"

```
secret_key                  = "~/.aws/credentials"
```

Getting error in GitHub
Error: Failed to get existing workspaces: Unable to list objects in S3 bucket "***": operation error S3: ListObjectsV2, https response error StatusCode: 400, RequestID: arn-1:xxxx, HostID: , api error AuthorizationHeaderMalformed: Unable to parse Authorization header AWS4-HMAC-SHA256

Any help or lead is much appreciated

I tried with setup default profile and secret using echo at GitHub runner  but facing this issue

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.